# Is Puppeteer making my NodeJS process to exit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm playing with Puppeteer and wrote this example (should probably never happen in production, but still):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // creating browser instance and closing it
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  browser.disconnect()
  await browser.close()

  console.log('first check') // everything is ok here, message is printed

  // opening page on the closed browser instance. Just for testing purposes
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('http://google.com')

  // never printed
  console.log('second check')
})()
```

So basically, I am trying to create a new page on a closed instance of the browser. Obviously, no page is opening because browser instance is closed. But I am expecting some error. Instead nothing happens **and the second** `console.log` **is never executed!.**

Question. If no error is thrown, why does the program never reach the second `console.log`? Does puppeteer somehow closes the process of my NodeJS application? Or I am missing something?

puppeteer version: latest - 5.3.1 (also 3.0.0)

By the way, if I use some earlier puppeteer version (2.0.0), same code is failing with error as I expect:

```
Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 2 (CLOSING)
```

---

Update.

After debugging a bit the internals of Puppeteer I found out the following:

They have a `Connection` class with the map of callbacks as a property. Whenever we call the `newPage` method, a connection with new id is created as well as a new corresponding `Promise`. This promise `resolve` and `reject` functions are assigned to the `callbacks` map:

```js
send(method, ...paramArgs) {
    const params = paramArgs.length ? paramArgs[0] : undefined;
    const id = this._rawSend({ method, params });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this._callbacks.set(id, { resolve, reject, error: new Error(), method });
    });
}
```

Then, the `Connection` class has the `_onMessage(message)` callback. Whenever some data (message) is received, they inspect the message to find out if it is an `OK` or an `ERROR` message. After this they invoke the stored `resolve` or `reject` callback.

But since the browser instance is my example is already closed, the message never arrives and the `Promise` is neither `resolved` nor `rejected`.

And after small research, I found out that NodeJS is not able to track such a `Promises`. Example:

```js
(async () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (true === false) {
      resolve(13) // this will never happen
    }
  })

  const value = await promise
  console.log(value) // we never come here
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this seems to be a bug.  I see the [issue you made](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6474) and added a potential fix.

Adding this as the first thing in Connection.send() seems to fix the issue:

```js
if (this._closed)
            return Promise.reject(new Error(`Protocol error (${method}): Target closed.`));
```

In the mean time, I have added this to my code so at least it doesn't die silently with no indication that it failed:

```js
process.on('beforeExit', (code) => {
        //beforeExit will run if out of callbacks, but not on an exit()
        console.log('We seem to be exiting purely because there are no more awaits scheduled instead of having reached and exit.  Assuming this is bad behavior from the browser process. previous exit code: ', code);
        process.exit(1); 
});


//my code goes here
asdf()

process.exit(0);//will exit without triggering the beforeExit message.
```

Honestly the behavior of Node in silently exiting seems like it is a little lacking.  You can set an exitCode, but having a program completely able to run up to an await then die silently without triggering exception handlers or finally blocks is a little gross.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any error probably because you don't wait for the `async` function to settle. If you attach a `catch` handler most likely you'll catch the error:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // creating browser instance and closing it
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  browser.disconnect()
  await browser.close()

  console.log('first check') // everything is ok here, message is printed

  // opening page on the closed browser instance. Just for testing purposes
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('http://google.com')

  // never printed
  console.log('second check')
})()
.then(() => console.log('done'))
.catch(e => console.error(e)); // <= HERE
```

Or use `try/catch`:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  try {
    // creating browser instance and closing it
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    browser.disconnect();
    await browser.close();

    console.log("first check"); // everything is ok here, message is printed

    // opening page on the closed browser instance. Just for testing purposes
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("http://google.com");

    // never printed
    console.log("second check");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: In my example the anonymous self-invoking function is used. In your first example you try to mix `async/await` API with `Promise` API which is not necessary and should be avoided. Your second example makes much more sense but still, if you run both of your suggested solutions you will see that "second check" is never printed because `newPage` promise is never resolved neither rejected and NodeJS is not able to await for such promises and exits (see the Update section I wrote).

Comment: "anonymous self-invoking" or not, an async function creates a promise and you need to wait for it to settle. Otherwise in case of failure it's `Unhandled Rejected Promise`. Good luck with your adventure.